# Printing Arrays java

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I am trying to print the second set of arrays in this code but I am only getting weird number outputs.

This is the instructions for my code: 
Using another for loop, print all the elements in the facevalue with each item in suit. This should produce a printout of a complete deck of cards as follows.

Here is my code:
Cards

```
   public static void main (String[] args)
   {
       int facevalue[] = new int[13];
       char suit[] = {'C', 'S','H', 'D' } ;
       for (int i=0; i<=facevalue.length-1;i++) {
           facevalue[i]=i+1;
           System.out.print(facevalue[i]+"\t");
       }
       /*for (int i = 0; i < facevalue.length-1; i++) {
             System.out.print(suit[0] + facevalue[i]);
        }*/
   }
```

It should be like c1 c2 , h1 h2 etc. thanks.

Comment: Because `character + number = number`. Where the character is converted into an ascii number. Cast your number to a string before trying to concatenate.

Answer (score 1):

According to docs [String.valueOf(char c)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(char)):

> Returns the string representation of the char argument.

So you have to edit your print like this:

```
System.out.print(suit[0] + String.valueOf(facevalue[1]));
```

And the output would be:

> C1C2C3C4C5C6C7C8C9C10C11C12

Answer (score 0):

When printing an int array, you will end up printing it's memory location instead. To prevent this, you will need to convert it from Int to string.

You can use:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(facevalue[i]+ "\t"));
```